# How do you stop a form's ajax events firing when and link inside the form is clicked?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, events, jquery-events

I have an ajax form like so...

```
<form action="/whatever" method="POST" id="blerg">
</form>
```

This an ajax event bound to it like this for when the form is submitted:

```
$("#blerg").bind('ajax:before', function(xhr, settings){
    alert("xxx");
}).bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){
    alert("xxx");
});
```

Now if I put a link in the form like so:

```
<form action="/whatever" method="POST" id="blerg">
    <a id="some_ajax_link" href="#">Some ajax link</a>
</form>
```

And then attach ajax events to that link too like so:

```
$("#some_ajax_link").bind('ajax:before', function(xhr, settings){
    alert("yyy");
}).bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){
    alert("yyy");
});
```

When I click the link inside the form. It triggers both the forms ajax events and then the links events too.

How do I make it so the link just fires it's own events and not it's the forms events that it's wrapped in?

Comment: Why do you use an AJAX form? Can't you just use a link, with `click` event bound to a function that calls an AJAX webservice?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use .bind() both in form and link? And if you use only a call when the link is clicked?

http://jsfiddle.net/bruno2c/nS5KS/2/

```
$('#some_ajax_link').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        /* insert a valid url here */
        url: "",
        data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            alert('yyy');
        },
        success: function (xhr) {
            alert('xxx');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$("#new_edit_text_style_form")
```

with

```
$("#blerg")
```

Comment: yeah, that's a mistake, i'ved fixed it, but it's not the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround, but perhaps it is helping you to avoid this problem. It still triggers both times, but the code (`alert("xxx");`) just runs when the right element has fired the event.

Here is a minimal example:

HTML:

```
<div id="header"> 
    <div id="content">
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    background-color: blue ;
    width: 100px ;
    height: 100px ;
}

#content {
    background-color: red ;
    width: 50px ;
    height: 50px ;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#header").bind('click', function(xhr, settings){
    if(xhr.originalEvent.srcElement == $(this)[0]) { // $(this) is the same as $("#header") in this case
        alert("xxx"); // this is only executed when clicked on the header
    }
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is applicable, but isn't this a job for

```
event.preventDefault()

    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>event.preventDefault demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://jquery.com">default click action is prevented</a>
<div id="log"></div>

<script>
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $( "<div>" )
    .append( "default " + event.type + " prevented" )
    .appendTo( "#log" );
});
</script>
```

Src: [JQuery Site](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit confusing.

If you want to prevent the hyperlink you can use:

```
$( "#some_ajax_link" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //yourcode
});
```

If you want to prevent the form submit, but run some javascript:

```
<form onsubmit="alert('stop submit'); return false;" >
```

or link it to any javascript functions like so:

HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return mySubmitFunction()">
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function mySubmitFunction(event) 
{ 
  event.preventDefault(); 
  try { 
     //add code here
  } catch {}; 
  return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem.
I haven't tested extensively, but the immediate answer I've come up with is to test whether *event.target == event.currentTarget* (so similar to efux example)

**event.target** should return the object that triggered the event (the link you clicked)
**event.currentTarget** should return the object the event listener was attached to (the form the link was inside). Same as the this[0] efux used in his answer.

So using your example:

```
$("#blerg").on('ajax:before', function(event){
  if (event.target = event.currentTarget) {
    alert("xxx");
  }
}).on('ajax:success', function(event){
  if (event.target = event.currentTarget) {
    alert("xxx");
  }
});

$("#some_ajax_link").on('ajax:before', function(event){
  if (event.target = event.currentTarget) {
    alert("yyy");
  }
}).on('ajax:success', function(event){
  if (event.target = event.currentTarget) {
    alert("yyy");
  }
});
```